# Is TCP slow start supposed to be enabled for VoIP SIP?

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory, voip, sip, voice

[TCP slow start](https://www.keycdn.com/support/tcp-slow-start) mechanism generally is pretty useful in most cases. But it is not so good and reasonable for short-lived TCP connections. Hence the question:
Should TCP slow start be used with SIP-over-TCP? And how can one ensure that some VoIP-device (client) has this option enabled? Or maybe it is the common practice to disable this mechanism in case of VoIP-devices.
Sorry, if obvious. Any explanations are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should TCP slow start be used with SIP-over-TCP?

SIP does not transfer large data with TCP. SIP is only used for signaling, the transport of the actual data (voice, video, ...) is done with RTP and thus using UDP. The SIP messages are small enough to not be affected by slow start. The control flow of SIP is not affected either by slow start since messages usually expect a response anyway.